# python float object has not attribute 'value'

Tags: python, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I have 4 shared variables . I am updating a pair based on which Process is running.Following is the code.

```
class App(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__ (self,process_id):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.process_id = process_id
   def run(self,X,Y,lock):
        while True: 
               with lock :
               #some calculations which returns x and y 
               print 'x and y returned are :',x,y
                 try:
                    X.value = x
                    Y.value = y
                 except Exception ,e:
                   print e
                 
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xL = Value('d',0.0)
    xR = Value('d',0.0)
    yL = Value('d',0.0)
    yR = Value('d',0.0)

    lock = Lock()

    a = A('1')
    b = B('2')
   
    process_a = Process(target = a.run, args(xL,yL,lock, ))  
    process_b = Process(target = b.run, args(xR,yR,lock, ))
   
    process_a.start()
    process_b.start()
```

This is the output :

> x and y returned are : 375 402
>
> 'float' object has no attribute 'value'

Any help . ?

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: 'float' object has no attribute 'value'
this is what its being shown on my terminal

Comment: @BryanOakley  , shouldn't xL object have a value assigned with it . ? 
i;ve just modified the code in the documentation a little bit 
here  : https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: That is only the last line of the error.  Please include the *complete* error message.

Comment: It appears that although you pass in `X` and `Y` as `multiprocessing.Value` (which does have a `value` attribute), you overwrite the name with a float somewhere in your calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the three parts of your code I've annotated with numbers in parentheses:

```
   def run(self,X,Y,lock):
        while True:
               #some calculations which returns x and y 
               with lock :
                 X.value = x
                 Y.value = y

                 # (3) you now try to access an attribute of the arguments
                 # called 'value'
                 print X.value , Y.value , self.process_id


if __name__ == '__main__':
    xL = Value('d',0.0) # (1) these variables are assigned some objects that
    xR = Value('d',0.0) # are returned by the function 'Value'
    yL = Value('d',0.0) 
    yR = Value('d',0.0) 

    lock = Lock()

    a = A('1')
    b = B('2')

    # (2) now your variables are being passed to the 'a.run' and 'b.run'
    # methods
    process_a = Process(target = a.run, args(xL,yL,lock, ))  
    process_b = Process(target = b.run, args(xR,yR,lock, ))

    process_a.start()
    process_b.start()
```

When you trace through the execution of your code, you can see that it is attempting to access an attribute called `value` in whatever objects are returned by the function `Value`. Your error message is telling you that `Value` is returning `float` objects, which do not have a `value` attribute.

One of the following things is (most likely) going wrong for you:

1. The function `Value` is not doing what you think it is, and it's returning floats when it shouldn't.
2. In your "some calculations which return x and y" code, you're overwriting the X and Y arguments with floats.

Comment: I think you're missing the root problem.  There is a big snip of code represented by the comment `#some calculations which returns x and y`.  I think it more likely that the OP assigns a float to `X` or `Y` somewhere in the snipped code.  (I checked that `multiprocessing.Value` does indeed have a `value` attribute.  The way he is calling `Value` is consistent with how `multiprocessing.Value` is documented.)  I could be wrong about this seeing as the OP has accepted this answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski You're absolutely correct. I've edited my answer to include that.